# Creating AutoShutdown Policy with Azure VM with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to create an auto shutdown policy with Powershell for my Azure VM, but keep running into this error:

> New-AzureRmResource : MissingRequiredProperty : Missing required property TargetResourceId.
>   At C:\Users\home\Documents\CreateAzureVM.ps1:167 char:1
>   + New-AzureRmResource -Location $Loc -ResourceId $ScheduledShutdownReso ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingRequiredProperty,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceCmdlet

I am at a lost on how to fix this error, this is my script piece so far:

```
 $SubscriptionId = $AzContext.Context.Subscription.Id;  
$VMResourceId = (Get-AzureRmVM).id
$ScheduledShutdownResourceId = "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$RSGName/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-$VMName"

$Properties = @{}
$Properties.Add('status', 'Enabled')
$Properties.Add('taskType', 'ComputeVmShutdownTask')
$Properties.Add('dailyRecurrence', @{'time'= 1159})
$Properties.Add('timeZoneId', "Eastern Standard Time")
$Properties.Add('notificationSettings', @{status='Disabled'; timeInMinutes=15})
$Properties.Add('targetResourceId', $VMResourceId)

#Error
New-AzureRmResource -Location $Loc -ResourceId $ScheduledShutdownResourceId -Properties $Properties -Force
```

Answer (score 6):

The cause:

This script  `$VMResourceId = (Get-AzureRmVM).id` is not for a specific VM. You should get a specific VM.

Try to use following Powershell scripts:

```
$SubscriptionId = $AzContext.Context.Subscription.Id
$VM = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name VMName
$VMResourceId = $VM.Id
$ScheduledShutdownResourceId = "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/wayneVMRG/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-$VMName"

$Properties = @{}
$Properties.Add('status', 'Enabled')
$Properties.Add('taskType', 'ComputeVmShutdownTask')
$Properties.Add('dailyRecurrence', @{'time'= 1159})
$Properties.Add('timeZoneId', "Eastern Standard Time")
$Properties.Add('notificationSettings', @{status='Disabled'; timeInMinutes=15})
$Properties.Add('targetResourceId', $VMResourceId)

#Error
New-AzureRmResource -Location eastus -ResourceId $ScheduledShutdownResourceId  -Properties $Properties  -Force
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here a loop to read the current configured value for Auto-shutdown of AZ vms (can easy add update/change/set based on Wayne Yang example above) 
Example will loop thru many subscription. 
:

```powershell
###################
##:List all subs which are enabled
#$AllSubID = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | Where {$_.State -eq "enabled"}).SubscriptionId
### above might not work depends on account, just get all below.
$AllSubID = (Get-AzureRmSubscription).SubscriptionId
Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format s) :: List of Subscription below"
$AllSubID


$AllVMList = @()
Foreach ($SubID in $AllSubID) {
Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscriptionid "$SubID"

##list all VMs
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM
Foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
    $VM = New-Object psobject -Property @{`
        "Subscriptionid" = $SubID;
        "ResourceGroupName" = $VM.ResourceGroupName;
        "VMName" = $VM.Name}
        $AllVMList += $VM | select Subscriptionid,ResourceGroupName,VMName
        }
}

$AllVMList

## Get AutoShutdown info
Foreach ($VM in $AllVMList) {
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format s) :: VM: $($VM.VMName) :: $($VM.ResourceGroupName) :: $($VM.Subscriptionid)"
    $ScheduledShutdownResourceId = "/subscriptions/$($VM.Subscriptionid)/resourceGroups/$($VM.ResourceGroupName)/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-$($VM.VMName)"
    ## Write-Output "$ScheduledShutdownResourceId"
    $VMShutdownInfo = get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $ScheduledShutdownResourceId
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format s) :: VM: $($VM.VMName) :: status: $($VMShutdownInfo.properties.status) ; taskType: $($VMShutdownInfo.properties.taskType) ; timeZoneId: $($VMShutdownInfo.properties.timeZoneId) ; dailyRecurrence: $($VMShutdownInfo.properties.dailyRecurrence) ;  "
}
###Done
```